# LocalStorage vs DOM onload

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have question about this code, Taking CS50's web programming:

```
<script>

// Set starting value of counter to 0
if (!localStorage.getItem('counter'))
localStorage.setItem('counter', 0);

// Load current value of counter
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
document.querySelector('#counter').innerHTML = 
localStorage.getItem('counter');

// Count every time button is clicked
document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
// Increment current counter
let counter = localStorage.getItem('counter');
counter++;

// Update counter
document.querySelector('#counter').innerHTML = counter;
localStorage.setItem('counter', counter);
}
});

</script>
```

Does LocalStorage loads before the DOMContentLoaded?
Can I actually run code before it gets to that line? 
Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Does it work?

Comment: Yup, it does. I asked because I want to apply it to some other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.  localStorage methods are synchronous and localStorage  is immediately available within the window. It has nothing to do with the DOM